# Get difference between dates with + or - added to it

Tags: javascript

I have this code that gives me the number difference between dates and it works well, but if the result it's negative I would like to add the - before the number and if its positive have a + before the number. How would I do that?

```
var item = '2014-08-30';
var today = '2014-09-04';
var date1 = new Date(today);
var date2 = new Date(item);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement, or possible a ternary. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you allready have it, remove `Math.abs()` in fifth line
and you will get `diffDays` positive or negative
so it would look like this:

```
var timeDiff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```